# Add onLongClickListener to tab on TabHost android

Tags: java, android, onlongclicklistener

On an app that I'm working on, I need a context menu to show up if a user performs a longClick on a tab, which would allow them to close the tab. I can't seem to find a way to add a listener to a tab though. I either need each tab to have its own listener or the listener needs to be able to tell which tab had the longClick performed on it, as it won't always be the active tab.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean a long press anywhere on the tab, or just on the button for the tab inside the TabHost?

Comment: Just on the button on the TabHost would be best, but if that's not possible then anywhere in the tab would be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate that an answer has been accepted but if you want to utilise the built-in `ContextMenu` capabilities rather than set `onLongClickListeners` on the `TabWidget` itself, you can do this as follows...

Example, my current `TabActivity` adds tabs in a `for` loop and to register each for context menu I do the following.

```
for (int tabNumber = 1; tabNumber < 8; tabNumber++) {
    ...
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(indicator).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    View v = tabWidget.getChildAt(tabNumber - 1);
    registerForContextMenu(v);
    ...
}
```

Then in my `Activity` I simply override `onCreateContextMenu(...)` and `onContextItemSelected (MenuItem item)`

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    ...
    // The parameter v is the actual tab view and not the TabWidget
    // this makes it easy to get the indicator text or its tag in order
    // to easily identify which tab was long-clicked and build the menu
    ...
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
    ...
    // Process selected item here
    ...
}
```

There's no need to set an `OnLongClickListener` on any views explicitly as that is done by the call to `registerForContextMenu(...)`. Also, the `ContextMenu` creation and selection handling is all handled for you by the `ContextMenu` methods exposed by `Activity`.

Unless you need to handle all of this stuff yourself (for a custom context menu layout for example) it seems easier to just use what's buit-in to `Activity`.

Comment: That was really easy. If I had thought to look for something like that it would have saved me a lot of time and effort. Now I know a lot of ways to not do this and one way to do it. Thanks

Comment: @nick: Glad to help. You'd think that something so easy to do would be more obvious but I have to admit it took me quite a while to work it out when I first started using tabbed activities. Well worth the effort though.

Answer (score 1):

A `TabWidget` is a View like any other; you should be able to register an `OnLongClickListener` with it via `myTabWidget.setOnClickListener` and use the `View` argument of `OnLongClickListener.onLongClick(View v)` to determine which tab was clicked.

When you use a `TabSpec` to register the indicator for each tab with your TabHost, if the resource you pass in has an associated ID, you should be able to use that ID to look up the tab itself.  This may mean you could have to start using `View`s or layouts as your `TabSpec.setContent` or `TabSpec.setIndicator` arguments (if you aren't already) so you can look them up by ID later.

Comment: That makes sense, I was looking in the TabHost.TabSpec class, which inherits from Object, but I figured there had to be some way to get it. Thanks